# Add Handler to Read Processed Value - OPC Advosol .Net Server ToolKit

Tags: opc

I am using Advosol OPC .Net Server Toolkit and trying to read Processed value from OPC Client But wanted to know how can I add handler for Processed value at server side ? How can I get Event of request of reading processed value from client side ? Please help me on this

Comment: What did you already try? Can you post a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?. Additionally please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You mean, you would like to have an event (on server side) at the moment when client requests reading given node value?